# AWS Step Function define Parameters and pass to next state

Tags: aws-step-functions

Lets say my input json contains `"raw_filename": "myfile"`.
In my first step, I have

```
"Parameters": {
  "file_a_path.$": "States.Format('s3:/mybucket/{}', $.raw_filename)"
  "file_b_path.$": "States.Format('s3:/mybucket/{}_firstprocess', $.raw_filename)"
}
```

Then this task can make use of that, eg process file A to create file B.
Now, in my next task, I want to process file B to make file C.  Is there any way I can pass this "file_b_path" as output to be input into the next step?

I know as a backup plan, if I set `"ResultPath": null` then it passes the original input along to the next step so I could use "raw_filename" again to redefine "file_b_path" in the parameters of the next step, but it would be more robust to pass it in.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
"Parameters":{
   "file_a_path.$":"States.Format('s3:/mybucket/{}',$.raw_filename)",
   "file_b_path.$":"States.Format('s3:/mybucket/{}_firstprocess', $.raw_filename)"},
"ResultSelector":{
   "result.$":"$.file_b_path"
}
},
"Next State":{
   "whatever.$" : "$.result"}
```

Are you trying to acheive somethng like this?

Comment: Is ResultSelector able to get values from the Parameters?  I thought it just filtered the return values from the task that was launched (eg the aws batch job).  (I can try this out later and see what I see)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to pass the evaluated field/values in the parameters field.

As you mentioned, you would need to re-evaluate the value of `file_b_path.$` in your next state.